# Are there templates for adding a search filter on a CartoDB embed?

Tags: carto, search-window

I'm looking for any examples of an embedded CartoDB map with a search filter built in. So, a map of schools, say, with a pulldown that will let you select one school and then zoom to it.

Or a map of schools and a pull down that will let you toggle between Elementary, Middle and High schools.

I know I can use filters or a custom query but I'm looking for something viewers of the final map can play with themselves.

Here's the deal: I'm trying to figure out what it would take to make a map that a colleague wants. If I have to do a lot of JS work, that's a bigger project. If there's a cut-and-paste solution that makes it easier. And if there's a GUI, they can make it themselves.

Comment: Denver Crime Map http://silverbiology.com/projects/cartodb/casestudies/denvercrime/# Maximize Filter

Comment: Are you looking for something out of the box? Or are you able to write basic Javascript?

Comment: @DuncanRager Updated my Q. I'm trying to get a handle on the scope of a project. Basic JavaScript isn't out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box, you could use the "Layer Selector" as a very simple solution to filtering categories. [Here is a link to a basic map](http://cdb.io/1no7mdB) I created with the option to toggle on and off cities and bodies of water. Here's a [video that shows the basics](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/multilayer_overview.html).

For a more custom application, like selecting a specific school and zooming to it, you'd likely need some HTML/Javascript. The basic logic would go something like this:

1. Use the CartoDB.js library to [create your map](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/create_map_cartodbjs.html) and set it up how you like
2. Create and Populate an HTML [drop box](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) (or similar element) with your school names, maybe grabbing them with an [SQL call](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#getting-data-with-sql)
3. Hook a mouse click [event handler](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) to each one of those choices that fires a function that zooms to the feature. Maybe [something like this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78130/cartodb-passing-selected-features-bounds-to-map-center-parameter-zoom-to-selec).

If you aren't familiar with HTML/CSS/Javascript/SQL, it would be an undertaking just to navigate and understand the API reference. If you're interested, Carto has [some examples](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#usage-examples) to get you started.

Bottom line, for layer toggling, you can just use the visualizations, but for zooming and other custom stuff, CartoDB.js is the ticket.